# Cursor position to CSS grid position

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid layout and want to get the cell position below my cursor.
Imagine the following example:

[image]

If my cursor is where the star in the image is, I’m looking for a javascript function which returns `{grid-row-start: 2, grid-row-end: 3, grid-column-start: 5, grid-column-end: 6}`.

Does anybody of you knows about a native function to do this? Or do i have to calculate the values myself?
Thanks :)

The code of my example looks like the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .container {
                display: grid;
                grid-gap: 10px;
                background-color: blue;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
                height: 400px;
            }
            .container div {
                background-color: green;
            }
            .grid-stack-item {
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="2" data-gs-height="1">
                <div class="grid-stack-item-content">1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-x="2" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="2" data-gs-height="2">
                <div class="grid-stack-item-content">2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-x="4" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="1" data-gs-height="1">
                <div class="grid-stack-item-content" style="overflow: hidden">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-x="5" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="1" data-gs-height="1">
                <div class="grid-stack-item-content"> 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="1" data-gs-width="1" data-gs-height="1">
                <div class="grid-stack-item-content">5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-x="1" data-gs-y="1" data-gs-width="1" data-gs-height="2">
                <div class="grid-stack-item-content">6</div>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="2" data-gs-width="1" data-gs-height="1">
                <div class="grid-stack-item-content">8</div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-x="2" data-gs-y="2" data-gs-width="2" data-gs-height="1">
                <div class="grid-stack-item-content">9</div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-x="4" data-gs-y="2" data-gs-width="1" data-gs-height="1">
                <div class="grid-stack-item-content">10</div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-stack-item" data-gs-x="5" data-gs-y="2" data-gs-width="1" data-gs-height="1">
                <div class="grid-stack-item-content">11</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script>
        for(let elm of document.getElementsByClassName('grid-stack-item')){
            elm.style['grid-column-start'] = parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-gs-x')) + 1;
            elm.style['grid-column-end'] = parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-gs-x')) + parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-gs-width')) + 1;
            elm.style['grid-row-start'] = parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-gs-y')) +1 ;
            elm.style['grid-row-end'] = parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-gs-y')) + parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-gs-height')) +1;
        }
    </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Simple question but what have you tried so far ? Have you do some research ?

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: I've added the code of my example. and yes, i did some research, but it's really hard to google something where you don't know the term to google for... i read through some pages at developer.mozilla.org and read about grid system but i could not find anything about a native javascript function to do what i want to do... Do you have a tip?

Comment: @johannchopin if the question is simple, do you have a simple answer? besides calculating it myself?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is figure out which element the mouse is over, and then get the `window.getComputedStyle(element).gridColumnStart` (and others) from that element.

The simplest way to do this would be to just add a `mouseenter` event to each of the `grid-stack-item` elements.

Here's a rough example:

```js
let currentCellPosition = {
  "grid-row-start": null,
  "grid-row-end": null,
  "grid-column-start": null,
  "grid-column-end": null
}

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("grid-stack-item")).forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    currentCellPosition = {
      "grid-row-start": style.gridRowStart,
      "grid-row-end": style.gridRowEnd,
      "grid-column-start": style.gridColumnStart,
      "grid-column-end": style.gridColumnEnd
    }
  })
})
```

In this example, `currentCellPosition` will always have the most recent cell position.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const output = document.getElementById("output");

  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("cell")).forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(element)
      output.innerHTML = `
      row start: ${style.gridRowStart}
      row end: ${style.gridRowEnd}
      column start: ${style.gridColumnStart}
      column end: ${style.gridColumnEnd}
      `;
    })
  })
});
```

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.a {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.b {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  background-color: orange;
}
.c {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a cell"></div>
  <div class="b cell"></div>
  <div class="c cell"></div>
</div>

<p id="output">

</p>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. That would work if i want to get the position of an element that is available in my grid. What i actually looking for is to get the (grid) position of an empty space. As you can see in the screenshot, below the star (as a symbol of my cursor) there is no green element!. So there also is no element on which i can bind the mouseenter-event..

Comment: @ehhc I don't think this is possible without computing it yourself. To compute it yourself, you'd need to take into account all the column and row sizes as well as gaps, so I don't recommend that.

Comment: What if you programmatically inserted an element at each grid cell and added the events to those?

Comment: that would get quiet ugly if the grid becomes big (e.g. with 1000 rows and 1000 columns)..

Comment: Why not add a secondary grid layer with identical square like chess. position it absolute and bind mouseenter to this layer. now you can grab your information. btw. @Ian answer was perfect and elegant

Answer (score 1):

the idea here is to add an extra grid layer beyond the container. lets call it "pseudoContainer".
This pseudoContainer will be absolute postioned.
It will contain elements in columns with 16,6% width and a heigth that will match to the grid.
Now we can bind the mouseenter to the pseudo elements.

Based on @Ian answer I have made a fiddle:

first create some pseudo elements:

```
var cont = $(".pseudoContainer");
for (var i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'pseudoitem');
  newDiv.innerHTML = '<div class="pseudoitem-inner"></div>';
  cont.append(newDiv);
}
```

then add listener:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("pseudoitem-inner")).forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    currentCellPosition = {
      "grid-row-start": style.gridRowStart,
      "grid-row-end": style.gridRowEnd,
      "grid-column-start": style.gridColumnStart,
      "grid-column-end": style.gridColumnEnd
    }
    console.log(currentCellPosition);
  })
})
```

with some styling you can see:

```
.pseudoContainer{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 3px;
   z-index:1;
}
.pseudoitem{
      width: calc(16.6% - 10px);
    height: 126px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px;
    z-index:2;
}
.pseudoitem-inner{
  background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.container{
  z-index:1;
}
.grid-stack-item{
  z-index:3;
}
```

now you only to refine the pseudo elements creation process so that they contain the grid information.

[here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattopen/bozvx93e/)

**EDIT:**
Now you will get the desired information onmouseover.
The way here is also to add an extra grid layer beyond the container and set position absolute.
Unfortunately this will work only for this grid and it is really not my best work.
In priciple it is the same as solution one but now make also use of grid style here.

```
var cont = $(".pseudoContainer");
var y,x;
for (var i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
if(i <= 5) y = 0, x = i;
if(i > 5 && i <= 11) y = 1, x = i - 6;
if(i > 11 && i <= 18) y = 2, x = i - 12;
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'pseudoitem');
  newDiv.setAttribute('data-gs-width', '1');
  newDiv.setAttribute('data-gs-height', '1');
  newDiv.setAttribute('data-gs-x', x);
  newDiv.setAttribute('data-gs-y', y);
  newDiv.innerHTML = '<div class="pseudoitem-inner"></div>';
  cont.append(newDiv);
}

for(let elm of document.getElementsByClassName('pseudoitem')){
            elm.style['grid-column-start'] = parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-gs-x')) + 1;
            elm.style['grid-column-end'] = parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-gs-x')) + parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-gs-width')) + 1;
            elm.style['grid-row-start'] = parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-gs-y')) +1 ;
            elm.style['grid-row-end'] = parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-gs-y')) + parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-gs-height')) +1;
        }


let currentCellPosition = {
  "grid-row-start": null,
  "grid-row-end": null,
  "grid-column-start": null,
  "grid-column-end": null
}

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("pseudoitem")).forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    currentCellPosition = {
      "grid-row-start": style.gridRowStart,
      "grid-row-end": style.gridRowEnd,
      "grid-column-start": style.gridColumnStart,
      "grid-column-end": style.gridColumnEnd
    }
    console.log(currentCellPosition);
  })
})
```

and the styling:

```
.pseudoContainer{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  width: 100%;
      height: 400px;
  display: grid;
   z-index:1;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
   grid-gap: 0px;
}
.pseudoitem{

    z-index:2;
}
.pseudoitem-inner{

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.container{
  z-index:1;
}
.grid-stack-item{
  z-index:3;
}
```

**EDIT2:**
I have rewritten the calculation. now you can define "repeat" and "rows" parameter and layer2 grid will be automatically created.

the fiddle is updated and here is the code change:

```
var cont = $(".pseudoContainer");
var y,x;
var repeat = 6;
var rows = 3;
for (var i = 0; i < rows*repeat; i++) {

  if(i%repeat === 0) {
    y = i/repeat;
  }
  x = i- y * repeat;

  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'pseudoitem');
  newDiv.setAttribute('data-gs-width', '1');
  newDiv.setAttribute('data-gs-height', '1');
  newDiv.setAttribute('data-gs-x', x);
  newDiv.setAttribute('data-gs-y', y);
  newDiv.innerHTML = '<div class="pseudoitem-inner"></div>';
  cont.append(newDiv);
}

for(let elm of document.getElementsByClassName('pseudoitem')){
            elm.style['grid-column-start'] = parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-gs-x')) + 1;
            elm.style['grid-column-end'] = parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-gs-x')) + parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-gs-width')) + 1;
            elm.style['grid-row-start'] = parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-gs-y')) +1 ;
            elm.style['grid-row-end'] = parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-gs-y')) + parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-gs-height')) +1;
        }


let currentCellPosition = {
  "grid-row-start": null,
  "grid-row-end": null,
  "grid-column-start": null,
  "grid-column-end": null
}

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("pseudoitem")).forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    currentCellPosition = {
      "grid-row-start": style.gridRowStart,
      "grid-row-end": style.gridRowEnd,
      "grid-column-start": style.gridColumnStart,
      "grid-column-end": style.gridColumnEnd
    }
    console.log(currentCellPosition);
  })
})
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think that adding a lot of additional elements only to do this might not scale well if there are a lot of rows and columns. I hoped for a browser-native solution without any workaround that i'm just not aware of. Nonetheless: thanks again for your example.

Comment: @ehhc you are welcome. The only thing that you need to enhance is the calculation of x and y within the for loop - and you are done. Then the solution will scale as you need.

Comment: @ehhc I have enhanced the calculation. Feel free and give it a second try.